# How to check a value is equal to any of the three values

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to check for each element the metadata data of book is (BOOK or LANGUAGE or FORMAT). With the code below I get this error:

```
Cannot invoke equalsIgnoreCase(String) on the primitive type boolean
```

```
List<MetaDataTypeEntity> bookMdtTypeEntity=(List<MetaDataTypeEntity>)
CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(getMetaDataTypes()).stream()
    .filter(data-> data.getMetaDataTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("BOOK").equalsIgnoreCase("LANGUAGE").equalsIgnoreCase("FORMAT"))
    .findAny().orElse(null);
```

I need to go inside of every object in list and check conditions BOOK And FORMAT LANGUAGE hierarchy. Please give me a code suggestion.

Comment: you want to check whether the value is BOOK|LANGUAGE|FORMAT correct?

Comment: Yes , I do same thing

Answer (score 1):

You can store three values in `Set`

```
Set<String> values = Set.of("BOOK","LANGUAGE","FORMAT");   //from java 9
```

And then use `contains`

```
MetaDataTypeEntity bookMdtTypeEntity= CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(getMetaDataTypes()).stream()
.filter(data-> values.contains(data.getMetaDataTypeName().toUpperCase()))
.findAny().orElse(null);
```

As @Holger suggested you can also use `TreeSet` for ignore case search, and also the most important thing `findAny` returns `Optional<MetaDataTypeEntity>` so the casting will fail since you are returning `MetaDataTypeEntity` and casting it into `List<MetaDataTypeEntity>`

```
Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
            set.add("BOOK");
            set.add("LANGUAGE");
            set.add("FORMAT");

MetaDataTypeEntity bookMdtTypeEntity= CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(getMetaDataTypes()).stream()
.filter(data-> values.contains(data.getMetaDataTypeName()))
.findAny().orElse(null);
```

Comment: `conatins` should be `contains`. And instead of performing `toUpperCase()` on every string (which might not even be sufficient for certain letters and locales), it's better to use a `new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)`, whose `contains` method would do the right lookup. Besides that, casting a `String` to `List<MetaDataTypeEntity>` will surely break at runtime.

Comment: I don't think there is any casting @Holger Just filtering based on `name` and returning the first matched `MetaDataTypeEntity` with that name. Correct me if i'm wrong ?

Comment: Isn't `List<MetaDataTypeEntity> bookMdtTypeEntity=(List<MetaDataTypeEntity>)...` casting the result (yes it's a `MetaDataTypeEntity` not a `String`) to a `List`?

Comment: That really make more sense thank you so much, updated my answer@Holger

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your condition, `.equalsIgnoreCase("BOOK")` returns `boolean` so you can't use `.equalsIgnoreCase("LANGUAGE")` on `boolean`.

Try following code:

```
List<MetaDataTypeEntity> bookMdtTypeEntity=(List<MetaDataTypeEntity>)
        CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(getMetaDataTypes()).stream()
                .filter(data-> data.getMetaDataTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("BOOK")
                        || data.getMetaDataTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("LANGUAGE")
                        || data.getMetaDataTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("FORMAT"))
                .findAny().orElse(null);
```